# Does the square of uniform distribution have density function?

Tags: probability

$X\sim U[0,1]$ and $Y\sim U[-1,1]$ are two uniform-distributed R.V.'s. Are $X^2$ and $Y^2$ still uniform? Do they have explicit probability density funtion?

Comment: It's not the square of the distribution; it's the distribution of the square. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are not uniform distribution.$$F_{X^2}(x) = \mathbb{P}(X^2 \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X \in [0,\sqrt{x}]) = \sqrt{x}$$
Hence,
$$f_{X^2}(x) = \dfrac{dF_{X^2}(x)}{dx} = \dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}$$
You can do the same thing for $Y \mapsto Y^2$.
$$F_{Y^2}(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y^2 \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in [-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}]) =  \sqrt{y}$$
Hence,
$$f_{Y^2}(y) = \dfrac{dF_{Y^2}(y)}{dy} = \dfrac1{2\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: Since the support of $X$ and $Y$ are different, shouldn't their distributions be different as well? Namely, isn't $F_{Y^2}(y) = 2\sqrt{y}$ and thus $f_{Y^2}(y)=1/\sqrt{y}$?

Comment: @JasonMorgan No. Note that $F_{Y^2}(1)$ should be $1$, which is not the case, with your answer.

Comment: Right. Thank you. I should have noticed that.

Comment: I don't understand a step of your proof: with $Y$ being uniform between $[-1,1]$ shouldn't the probability of an interval $[a,b]$ be $\frac{1}{b-a}$ and therefore the $\mathbb{P}(Y \in [-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}]) =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$

Comment: @Matteo no, be  careful about the integrand

Comment: @aflous - is it because y is under a square root and thus needs to be positive (so between 0 and 1)?

Comment: No, $ \mathbb{P}(Y \in [-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}]) = \frac{\sqrt{y} -(-\sqrt{y})}{b-a}=\frac{2\sqrt{y}}{1-(-1)}= \frac{2\sqrt{y} }{2}=\sqrt{y}$

Comment: why doesn't this work? $E(y^2)=\int_{-1}^{1}y^2\frac{1}{2}dy=\int_0^1y^2dy?$

Comment: What are the domain of $y$, is it $y \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 3):

First, find the CDF of the transformed RV.
Let $S = X^2$.

$P(S \leq s) = P(X^2 \leq s) = P(X \leq \sqrt s) = \sqrt s$, for $0 < s < 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Where the last equality is true since $X$ ~ $\text{Unif}(0,1).$ Note, in general, the support is not the same under the transform.

Next, differentiate to find the PDF.
$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{s} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt s}$ for $0 \leq s \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

The PDF of $Y^2$ follows similarly. Also, in general, uniformity is not preserved under non-linear transforms.

Comment: The PDF is not defined at 0 or 1, although it can be set to 1/2 at 1 by convention.