# PDF for $\frac1a Uniform(−a,a)$

Tags: probability-theory, transformation, uniform-distribution

Problem: Let $X$ be $Uniform(−a,a)$ distrubuted. Calculate the PDF for $Z = \frac1a abs(X)$.

Attempt: I think graphically here. $X$ is $U(-a,a)$ with $PDF = \frac1{2a}$ so $abs(X)$ is $U(0,a)$ with $PDF = \frac1a$ and thus PDF for $Z = \frac1a \cdot \frac1a = \frac1{a^2}$ with support on $x \in [0,a]$.

I do know that I could use the inverse tranform method and do like this question [Does the square of uniform distribution have density function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305997/does-the-square-of-uniform-distribution-have-density-function). My first thought was to do this and  put calculate PDF for $Z^2$ since I do not like working with abs() but I canno tdo that since $\sqrt{Z^2} \neq Z$ due to the fact that Z har support on $[-a,a]$.

Comment: In your attempt, the PDF you derived does not integrate to one.

Comment: @JanoKakara No it does not. I cannot figure out the gap in my reasoning.

Comment: why the pdf of Z is calculated like that?

Comment: Hint: If $U$ is uniform on $(0,a)$, what is the range of $U/a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt, the first step is correct, that is really $\left\vert X \right\vert$ is distributed as $U \sim Uniform(0,a)$ with distribution function 
$$ F_U(u) = \begin{cases} u/a & \mbox{ for }0 \leq u \leq a, \\ 0 & \mbox{ for }u < 0, \\ 1 & \mbox{ for }u > a. \end{cases}$$
However, then you must obtain the distribution of $Z = U/a$, and the easiest way to do this is through its distribution function
$$ F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(U/a \leq Z) = P(U \leq a z) = F_U(a z) = \begin{cases}  a z /a & \mbox{ for }0 \leq a z \leq a, \\ 0 & \mbox{ for }z<0/a, \\ 1 & \mbox{ for }z>a/a. \end{cases}$$
Thus, $U/a$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.