# Find the distribution for probabilities of circle area

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The size of the radius of a circle is uniform on the interval $[a,b]$ $(0<a<b)$ find the distribution for the probabilities of the circles area, it's mathematical expectation and variance.

I have no clue on how to start this problem.

Comment: It will be similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305997/does-the-square-of-uniform-distribution-have-density-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
Here, $R \sim U(a,b)$ and $A = \pi R^2$, so the cdf of $A$ is
$$
F_A(x) = \mathbb{P}[A \le x] = \mathbb{P}\left[R \le \sqrt{x/\pi}\right]
       = F_R \left(\sqrt{x/\pi}\right)
$$

Can you plug into this the value of $F_R$ and use the fact that $f_A(x) = F_A'(x)$ to derive the pdf, and then the expectation and variance?

Comment: You could also use: $\displaystyle\mathsf E( g(R)) ~=~ \int_a^b \frac {g(r)}{b-a}\operatorname d r$

Comment: @GrahamKemp if this were an answer, I would upvote that and recommend instead of mine -- much easier to take 2 quick integrals than bother with the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in my answer...