# Is $EXX^2 = EX^3$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ (respectively, $X^2$) be a random variable with a given probability density function $f_X$ (respectively, $f_{X^2}$).

Is the following statement true:

$$EXX^2 = EX^3 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_{X^2}\left(x\right) f_X\left( x \right)\;dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^3f_{X}\left( x \right)\;dx $$

I've tried this on some example functions and it really seems to hold true. But I cannot say for certain.

Comment: $XX^2 = X^3$??? Also you tacitly assumed $X$ and $X^2$ are independent in the third part of your equation.

Comment: $f_X \cdot f_{X^2}$ is not the density function for $X(X^2)$; it is the density for $YX^2$ where $Y$ is an independent copy of $X$.

Comment: When you say "$X$ ($X^2$) is a random variable", do you mean "$Y$ is a random variable, where $Y=X(X^2)$," or do you mean "$X$ and $X^2$ are random variables"?

Comment: Well since $X$ is formally a function I think it is not obvious it should work like this. The last part of the equation is right?

Comment: I mean $X$ and $X^2$ are random variables (obviously dependent), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've inserted a couple of words to clarify what I think you meant to write. You can further edit the question or roll back my edit if it isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

$X X^2 = X^3$ of course, and $\mathbb E X^3 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 f_X(x)\; dx$ by the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.  But
$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X}(x) f_{X^2}(x^2)\; dx$ makes no sense.

Comment: It was meant to be $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X}(x) f_{X^2}(x)\; dx$. And in case $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, is $EXY = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(x)\; dx$? I think it doesn't work only because $X$ and $X^2$ are dependent, right?

Comment: @SlowerPhoton $X,X^2$ are dependent... often. If not, then $X^2$ is constant almost surely.

Comment: I am not saying they aren't.

Comment: No, the formula for independent random variables would be $$\mathbb E [XY] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x y f_X(x) f_Y(y)\; dx \; dy = \mathbb E[X] \mathbb E[Y]$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \sim U[0,1].$
Then 
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 \leq x\leq 1,\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f_{X^2}(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x} & 0 \leq x\leq 1,\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

(See [Does the square of uniform distribution have density function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305997/does-the-square-of-uniform-distribution-have-density-function))

Therefore
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X^2}(x) f_X( x )\;dx
= \int_0^1 \dfrac{\sqrt x}{2}\;dx = \frac 13
$$
whereas
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 f_X( x )\;dx
= \int_0^1 x^3 \;dx = \frac 14.
$$
And indeed $E(X^3) = \frac14.$

In general, it's true that 
$E(XX^2) = E(X^3) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 f_X( x )\;dx,$
but the middle part of your sequence of equations isn't generally correct.